# Is there a sequence $(x_n)$ with $f_n(x_n)=1$ and $f_n(x_{n+1})=0$ in a compact space?

Tags: general-topology

$(X,\mathcal T)$ is a Hausdorff compact topological space. For each $n\in \Bbb N$,
$$f_n:X\to [0,1]$$
is a continuous function and
$$x_n\in X$$
is any element such that
$$f_n(x_n)=1$$
$$f_n(x_{n+1})=0$$

Can we reach a contradiction?

Comment: No, indeed, if the space is relatively nice, we can find such a sequence $f_n$ for any sequence $x_n$

Comment: Can I know a little background of this question?

Comment: just a raw guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we reach a contradiction?

Why should we? Try $X=[0,1]$, $f_{2n}(x)=x$, $f_{2n+1}(x)=1-x$, $x_{2n}=1$, $x_{2n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X = \omega + 1$, and define $f_n : X \to [0,1]$ by $$f_n ( i ) = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if }i > n\text{ (or }i = \omega\text{)}\\
1, &\text{if }i \leq n
\end{cases}$$
Now let $x_n = n$ for all $n$.